# Javascript expression shortage: value? value:'100'

Tags: javascript, if-statement, expression

Is there any shorter way to write the expression

```
value? value:'100'
```

the way I don't type `value` twice?

Something like (but it is wrong)

`value? : '100'` //take value unless it is empty/null/false/undefined/0, otherwise accept '100'.

Or, whatever is possible would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_%28.7C.7C%29):

```
value || '100'
```

It'll return `value` if it's *truthy* (`!!value === true`), else `'100'`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you are in a ES2015 compatible environment you can use default values for you function arguments, too

```
 function( value = 100 ) {
   //now value is 100 if falsy
 }
```